# Why is this throwing "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two column form which has left and right dropdown menus.

Depending on what the user selects in the left dropdown, the right dropdown will render either as a plain dropdown (`<select>`) or a multiselect (`<select multiple="multiple">`) and populate values.

It mostly works, but I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error in the console when adding a row and then changing the left dropdown selection in the newly added row. The code works as intended (it updates the right dropdown), but I'm not sure why it's throwing the error in the first place.

Example:

```js
const regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
let cloneIndex = $(".operation").length;

bindToSelector($('.operation-keys'));

function setIndex(elements) {
  elements.each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).find("select.operation-keys").attr("name", "operation-keys[" + index + "]");
    $(element).find("select.operation-values").attr("name", "operation-values[" + index + "]");
  });
}

function clone() {

  let $removeButton = $(this).closest(".actions").find(".remove-operation");
  let $closestOperation = $(this).closest(".actions").prev(".operation").first();

  $removeButton.show();

  let selector = $closestOperation.clone()
    .insertAfter($closestOperation).attr("id", "operation-" + cloneIndex)
    .find("*")
    .each(function() {
      let id = this.id || "";
      let match = id.match(regex) || [];
      if (match.length == 3) {
        this.id = match[1] + '-' + (cloneIndex);
      }
    });
  cloneIndex++;

  let $Operations = $(this).closest(".operation-parent").find(".operation");

  setIndex($Operations);

  bindToSelector(selector);
}

function remove() {
  $(this).closest(".actions").prev(".operation").remove();

  let $Operations = $(this).closest(".operation-parent").find(".operation");
  setIndex($Operations);
  let totalElements = $(this).closest(".operation-parent").find(".operation").length;
  if (totalElements === 1) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
  cloneIndex--;
}

$(".add-operation").on("click", clone);
$(".remove-operation").on("click", remove);

// select logic

function buildSelect(operationKey) {
  let result = {};
  switch (operationKey) {
    case 'continents':
      result['operationValues'] = ['North America', 'South America', 'Europe'];
      result['type'] = 'multiple';
      break;
    case 'languages':
      result['operationValues'] = ['English', 'French', 'Spanish'];
      result['type'] = 'multiple';
      break;
    case 'eye_color':
      result['operationValues'] = ['Brown', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Hazel'];
      result['type'] = 'single';
      break;
    case 'age':
      result['operationValues'] = ['18-24', '25-32', '33-40', '>41'];
      result['type'] = 'single';
      break;
  }
  return result;
}

function bindToSelector(selector) {
  $(selector).on('change', function() {
    let operationKey = $(this).val()
    let valueSelect = $(this).parent().next().find('.operation-values');
    
    // get the values + type of select we should populate
    let result = buildSelect(operationKey);
    // set the select type, if needed
    if (result['type'] == 'multiple') {
      valueSelect.attr("multiple", "multiple");
    }
    else
    {
      valueSelect.removeAttr("multiple", "multiple");
    }

    // populate the values
    let options = result['operationValues'];
    console.log(options);
    
    // empty the dropdown in the cloned row (not working - empties all value dropdowns)
    valueSelect.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      valueSelect.append(`<option value="${options[i].toLowerCase()}" >${options[i]}</option>`);
    }

  });

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-4">Operation Key</label>
  <label class="col-6">Operation Value</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="operation-parent row">
    <div class="col-8 operation">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg operation-keys" name="operation_keys[]">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select One</option>
            <option value="continents">Continents Visited</option>
            <option value="languages">Languages Spoken</option>
            <option value="eye_color">Eye Color</option>
            <option value="age">Age</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg mb-30 operation-values" name="operation_values[]">

          </select>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 actions">
      <a class="btn btn-alt-success add-operation">+</a>
      <a class="btn btn-alt-danger remove-operation" style="display:none;">-</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The offending line is:

`for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {`

I'm just not understanding why it's throwing the error in the first place.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the snippet, make a selection in the left dropdown.
2. Click the `+` to add a new row.
3. Make a selection in the left dropdown of the new row. Observe error in console.

**Bonus points**: When adding a new row (step #2 above), how do I clear the values in the right dropdown of the new row (so it's not the same as the cloned row)? I know I need to call `.empty();` on a selector somewhere toward the end of `clone()`, but not sure what selector I should use.

Comment: Whoa, you changed the question, that was disorienting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your clone function:

```
let selector = $closestOperation.clone()
.insertAfter($closestOperation).attr("id", "operation-" + cloneIndex)
.find("*")
.each(function() {
  let id = this.id || "";
  let match = id.match(regex) || [];
  if (match.length == 3) {
    this.id = match[1] + '-' + (cloneIndex);
  }
});
// ...
bindToSelector(selector);
```

When you run the .find("*"), your selector is becoming a large array of 10 items. Each of these is then getting sent to your selector function and bound to the event handler.

When you change the value, these items are run through your `buildSelect` function, but don't match anything, since you were only expecting the select element to be sent through it. Thus the default value of `{}` gets returned. This empty object does NOT have the value "operationValues" which you try to access with `result['operationValues']`, so it is undefined and therefore has no length.

Comment: By the way, if you just break that into two lines your problem should go away. i.e. first declare that "selector" (and you can go ahead and append it without problem). Then end that statement with a semicolon, and resume what you want to do on the next line with "selector.find...". The problem is .find() changed the return value you were assigning to the variable, but separating the lines means that return value isnt assigned to anything.